# AWS Elasticsearch Service on http

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

How can I launch an aws elasticsearch service that accepts http requests? (Non secure). Is it possible?

So far, I managed to create a service that can only receive https request(secure), and I can't find a way to enable http requests(non secure).

Comment: i doubt this is possible

Comment: But why? Any reason to do that?

Comment: @Marcin I'm trying to connect from Enterprise Search but there's clearly a bug and very little documentation. I get along just fine connecting to unsecure elasticsearch hosts. I posted this here (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/enterprise-search-error-key-not-found-plugins-at-org-jruby-rubyhash-javain-fetch/280259) but I am guessing there isn't much support for non elastic cloud users.

Comment: Enterprise Search does not work the AWS Elasticsearch, it will only work with Elastic's distribution using at least the free license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
aws es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name <domain-name> --elasticsearch-version 7.10 \
--elasticsearch-cluster-config InstanceType=t3.small.elasticsearch,InstanceCount=1 \
--ebs-options EBSEnabled=true,VolumeType=gp2,VolumeSize=10 \
--domain-endpoint-options '{"EnforceHTTPS": false,"TLSSecurityPolicy": "Policy-Min-TLS-1-0-2019-07"}'
```